# Is there a way to change a variable value every time a group of functions in called in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, class, methods

Lets say I have a code like this. I want to change modified to LocalDateTime.now() when class methods are called

```
class Invoice(val items: Items)
    {
    private var modified: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

    //example functions (contents aren't important)
    // I want to change modified = LocalDateTime.now() everytime any of these functions are called
    val put: (String, Item) -> Unit = { key, value -> items.put(key, value) }
    val remove: (String) -> Unit = { key -> items.remove(key) }
    val updatePrice: (String, BigDecimal) -> Unit = { key, price -> items.updatePrice(key, price) 
}
```

I could write something like this in every function:

```
 val put: (String, Item) -> Unit = { key, value ->
        items.put(key, value)
        modified = LocalDateTime.now()
    }
```

But I'm wondering if there's a shorter way instead of manually writing this line of code to every function (to avoid code repetition)

Comment: Does it matter if the property is set *before* or *after* the function is run?

Comment: Also why don't you declare the methods as actual methods, but instead as properties of a function type?

Comment: Take a look at the [`observable()` delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#observable-properties). You could use this as a basis to define your own delegate. I would be wary of concurrent modification though.

Comment: The [observer pattern](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/observer-pattern) might be of interest.

Comment: Create yourself an Annotation with an implementation that calls `modified = LocalDateTime.now()`.  Then add this annotation to each method that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract that line of code into a new function:

```
fun updateModified() {
   modified = LocalDateTime.now()
}
```

Ultimately, you will need a way to mark each of those put/update/remove functions as updating the `modified` variable anyway, even if you used a delegate or an annotation. I see no reason to do something funny like using those or other fancy solutions rather than just a function call.

Even the fanciest solution will require you to type at least one symbol, but a function call is not only just one symbol, but also easy to understand and maintain.